# Gamekit / Gamecenter achievements not reporting correctly during testing

Tags: swift, swiftui, game-center, gamekit, achievements

I am currently working on a Swift/SwiftUI game with GameCenter / Gamekit integration.

I have successfully integrated game kit for leaderboards/scores, but I am having issues with achievements.

At the moment I am not sure if the problem lies with the testing procedure or with the code itself.

Just for background:

- App is currently published in the app store with a live leaderboard
- App version that is published does not have any achievements
- I have added achievements to the AppStoreConnect section

```
                    if self.parent.levelCount == 5 {
                        print("I Entered Level 5")
                        
                        
                        let achievement = GKAchievement.init(identifier: "level5", player: GKLocalPlayer.local)
                          achievement.percentComplete = 100
                          achievement.showsCompletionBanner = true
                        
                          GKAchievement.report([achievement]) { (error) in
                            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                          }
                        
                        
                    }
```

The above code runs, it enters the loop once the user reaches level 5, I get no errors, but I am unable to see the achievements once I enter gamecenter.

Is there something I need to change in the testing procedure in order to see achievements before publishing a new version of the app?

Or am I doing something wrong with the implementation of the code?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a little bit in the Apple developer forums I was able to find other users with the same issue.

In order to test achievements in the development version of the application, you must go to AppStore connect and in a new version of the app toggle the achievements you are testing (you do not need to publish the version).

Answer (score 0):

[image: AppStore connect section of achievements added to app]

As mentioned by Daniel DE you have to create the app version you want to attach the achievements to. Also make sure that you created an achievement in the Services -> GameCenter tab before. Then add the achievements to your version and they should show up after some time in your app.